# why my application getting crash in my iPod?

Tags: iphone

I am adding UIImageView on UIScrollView but my app getting crash when array count is high.

Here is my code

```
scr=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 320)];
        scr.tag=1000;
        [scr setDelegate:self];
        [self.view addSubview:scr];

        dispatch_queue_t queeee =dispatch_queue_create("raj", 0);

        int countt=200;
        for(int i=0;i<countt;i++)
        {

            CGRect rectt=CGRectMake((i%3*90)+30,(i/3*90)+40,80,70);

            UIImageView *asyImagee = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rectt];            

            dispatch_async(queeee, ^{

            NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"]];

            __block UIImage *imgg=[UIImage imageWithData:data];


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                               {
                                   asyImagee.image=imgg;
                                   imgg=nil;
                               });
            });

            asyImagee.tag=i;
            [scr addSubview:asyImagee];
            asyImagee=nil;
        }
        [scr setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, countt/3*110)];
```

Working fine with int countt=100;
 but crash with 200;

Comment: seems like a memory issue for me

Comment: are you working in background thread?

Comment: Do you receive a Memory Warning ? Is `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` called?

Comment: yes .. m working in background thread..

Comment: no in this code there is not any memory warnings.... direct ending of application